# google analytics dose not count every hit and session

Tags: google-analytics, statistics

i have two websites (i.e siteA.com and siteB.com) siteA.com act as a publisher and there is link with utm on siteA.com.

when the link is clicked the click info is saved and then it redirects to siteB.com.

siteB.com act as a landing page and google analytic js code is in this page.

but when i open google analytics there is difference between number of hits and session that i have saved from what is shown on google analytics.

google analytics shows me that only 14 session and devices have visited siteB.com from the link but my statics shows that 60 different devices have visited siteB.com from the link provided on siteA.com.

where does this inconsistency come from?

the click infos that i collect are (ip address, user agent, country, screen size and so on)

Answer (score 0):

Hit is a different metric than session. Default session duration in GA is 30 mins. That means one user can open your siteB.com 10 times (10 hits) but it will be still counted as 1 session (if it happens during 30mins from the same browser).

Comment: i know the difference between the session and hit. the issue here is that ga does not count hit when the landing page is hit